# vim - cabbr for 30 <C-w> v

Tags: vim

In vim I'd like to create a command abbreviation for the key strokes `30 <C-w> v`, i.e. split the current window vertically at a width of 30 characters.

This in my `.vimrc` file, however, gives: `E148: Regular expression missing from global`:

```
cabbr SomeCommand 30 <C-w> v
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: If you want to redefine new commands it is better to use `command` than `abbr`. The latter are rather used to replace typo and such like `iab teh the`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command sequence won't work in command mode, use the following instead:

```
cabbr SomeCommand 30vs
```

Answer (score 4):

`c_CTRL-W` does not mean anything to vim. Is it for the normal mode? The equivalent of `:vsplit`? If so, just use `vs`. And in that case, I fail to see the point of a command abbreviation. `30vs` is only 4 keys long.